# Fix a bug with dict comprehension

Tags: python

I have the following pattern:

```
episodes = {key: value for key, value in 
                  item_data['seasons'][season_id]['episodes'].items() 
              if (item_data['seasons'][season_id].get('episodes') and key.isdigit())}
```

Unfortunately, sometimes `'episodes'`, will be null, causing the following error:

```
KeyError: 'episodes'
```

What would be an elegant way to fix the above? My current solution does the following:

```
episodes = {key: value for key, value in item_data['seasons'][season_id].get('episodes')
            if item_data['seasons'][season_id].get('episodes')}
episodes = {key: value for key, value in item_data['seasons'][season_id]['episodes'].items()
            if key.isdigit()}
```

Comment: i'd not use comprehension here.

Comment: Neither would I - I'd assign the contents to a variable, then iterate its keys and remove any that aren't digits. Otherwise, I'd use `filter`.

Comment: That's not the question though :) OP asked us to point out the bug in their dict comprehension, so that's what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
episodes = {
    key: value for
    key, value in 
    item_data['seasons'][season_id].get('episodes', {}).items() 
    if key.isdigit()
}
```

Note that the first part of your `if` filter isn't necessary, since `{}.items()` has no keys :)